# Error trying to run rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new in ros, when I try to run rviz on my laptop I get the following crash message:

[ INFO] [1308585496.864793126]: Loading general config from [/home/d*/.rviz/config]

[ INFO] [1308585496.865195551]: Loading display config from [/home/d*/.rviz/display_config]

The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.

This probably reflects a bug in the program.

The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.

(Details: serial 28 error_code 3 request_code 138 minor_code 4)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

my laptop has an nvidia gts 360m and the version 260.19.44 of nvidia driver.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10329/error-trying-to-run-rviz/) by [davincho84](https://answers.ros.org/users/717/davincho84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-06-20**:
Hi, I am running the latest nvidia driver (270.41.19) on my gts 360m with Lucid without problems.  Can you check to make sure nvidia module is loaded (lsmod) and post the output from glxinfo?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disable (uninstall) your nVidia proprietary drivers. Reboot, then try again. This started happening to me after I enabled the proprietary drivers for my ATI Radeon card.

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davincho84](https://answers.ros.org/users/717/davincho84/) on 2011-06-21**:
problem solved reinstalling the nvidia drivers. thanks.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-20**:
Nvidia has much better proprietary drivers than ATI, they usually work better than the open source drivers.